# How to dynamically modify HTML with Xcode?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, xcode, html-parsing

I'm trying to make an iPhone app for a uni project.

The app should let the user change via touch some content of a web (text of labels, colour and font of the text, etc). The goal is to let the user play with different designs without coding.

I've thought of parsing a web, and add some functions to make the elements touchable, and then "reload" the modified `HTML`.

I'd like to know if this is "possible", I've found some parsers that work on `Xcode`, and adding functions is just coding with the parsed info... but can I reload that parsed and modified html from a variable (and continue working with it) instead of the original web `HTML`?

The other way is not to parse and modify the content with `JQuery`, but I don't know if it can be linked to Xcode since it works directly on web...

I'm a bit lost because i've almost always worked on desktop apps, so any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the web page once and modify it via JavaScript

```
   [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:myJavaScript];
```

Comment: That's what I finally did :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put some `JQuery` in your `HTML` file, then load that file into a `UIWebVIew`, it should work fine. There is no point making something like this too complicated.

`JQuery` is a client side tool, so loading into a web view will allow you to perform your dynamic changing of the `DOM`, without having to make things more complicated by parsing the oringal `HTML` markup

That is how I would do it.

Comment: Yeah that would do, but I can't put code directly into the HTML :( the app should make ANY web "touchable" (like hacking any web to make it modifiable)
That's why I'm making things complicated hahaha U_U
Thanks :)

Comment: I see, i thought it was a fixed page. What about downloading the HTML, adding the JQuery at the bottom to customise the page. Saving the new HTML as file, and loading that in a UIWebView?

Comment: Downloading the html via code and saving the file inside a folder in the device? (I can't do it manually, the app should open any web (like a browser) and make it touchable)
Isn't better parsing it? but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: You can still. Have a text bar with a URL, make a request to get the HTML, edit it, then display in a uiwebview. You can use something like NSURLRequest to get the HTML.